# Force type error when string doesn't match key of object

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 4.4.3, how can I cause the incorrect string `'c'` below to show a type error, (because it is not one of the keys of the object that is the first parameter of the `doSomething` method)?

```
const doSomething = ({ a, b }: { a: number, b: string }): boolean => {
  return a === 1 || b === 'secret'
}

type SomethingParameterName = keyof Parameters<typeof doSomething>[0]

const orderedParameterNames = [
  'b', 'c', 'a' // why no type error for 'c'?
] as SomethingParameterName[]
```

See [this code at TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMAKBDAJzyWAgIDljoBeKAawhDgDMp8iSyBnAHgApQkFlAAmceCXTYAlAD4A2gAYAugCgAxnAxdgo8YmRSsUWnwDeUPABooAIygBfAFxQLeFxgCuCW2Ru2XHQJMYwdpF1s4OAAbCDwME1lXVSgoAmRPAgS8E2paAEYoAB8iu1zaAHIuCHV04ArVB1UNLR0oOAIRMggRdipSCiouEyh5FKgK2wqbCvUKy2GJQxC+zkGkGbx5gHptqAB3FBAoDDgoQWgyAg6oZhvZioB+VWUF2ANUFcJ+skokeTUQA).

I played around with `const` a bit, and directly tried `'c' as SomethingParameterName` but that also gives no type error. In this case, I don't have an easy way to get the list of keys from another source than the function itself.

Comment: Because you are using `as`, which tells compiler you know what the type is. You should use `const orderedParameterNames: SomethingParameterName[]` to let the compiler check the type for you.

Comment: You're using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which prevents the compiler from telling you it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript construct `as TypeName` is essentially a type-cast. Because the base type of a union of const strings is `string`, TypeScript accepts this type-cast as a compatible [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). To get the expected error, define the type of the variable `orderedParameterNames`, instead of casting the value that is being assigned to it:

```
const orderedParameterNames: SomethingParameterName[] = [
  'b', 'c', 'a'
]
```

This will now give an error on `'c'`:

> TS2322: Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b".